# Cannot add the numbers from the file

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am having a problem with a code. 
1 - Gold
2 - Silver
3 - Bronze

What I am trying to do is that count how many gold medals are achieved each year. For example, in 2002, there is total of 2 gold medals, 1 silver, and 1 bronze.

code:

```
def main():
    year = str(input("Enter year to count its winners: "))
    goldmedal = 0
    openFile = open("test.txt")
    gold = "1"
    for line in openFile.read().split('\n'):
        if year in line:
            if str(1) in line:
                goldmedal = goldmedal + 1   
    print("Gold Medals: ", gold medal)
```

Expected output:

```
Enter year to count its winners: 2002
Gold Medals: 2
```

textfile:

```
WHEELER
ADAM
2001
3

KHUSHTOV
ASLANBEK
2002
1

LOPEZ
MIJAIN
2002
1

BAROEV
KHASAN
2002
2

BAROEV
KHASAN
2002
3
```

Comment: Your code looks for the Year, and whether the medal is gold ("1") on the same line in the file, which wont work.

Comment: @TonySuffolk66 Then how would I count the number of golds in one year?

Comment: see my answer - given two solutions -  one trying to fix your code, and one giving a better solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code is a bad (tm) fix - it assumes that the data is right, and sets a flag when it finds the right year. This is not a good solution : a better solution (in my opinion) is to load the data into a data structure first (maybe a dictionary), and then search the dictionary

```
from __future__ import print_function
def main():
    year = str(input("Enter year to count its winners: "))
    goldmedal = 0
    found_year = False
    openFile = open("test.txt")
    gold = "1"
    for line in openFile.read().split('\n'):
        if year in line:
            found_year = True
            continue:

        if found_year:
            if gold in line:
                goldmedal = goldmedal + 1
            found_year = False  

print("Gold Medals: ", goldmedal)
```

A better solution is this:

```
from __future__ import print_function
def main():
    winners = []
    with open("test.txt") as openfile:
         surname, firstname, year, medal, blank = next(openfile), next(openfile), next(openfile), next(openfile), next(openfile)
         winners.append({"Surname":surname,"Firstname":firstname,"Medal":medal})

   year = str(input("Enter year to count its winners: "))
   goldcount = sum([1 for winner in winners if winner.year=year and medal=1])
   print ("Gold Medals", goldcount)
```

Note : These should be ok, but I have not tested either.

Comment: Quick question, when printing out the Gold Medals, how do I remove ('')? like ('Gold Medals', 2).

Comment: I have added an import to make print the way you want - you are trying to use print as a function, but you are using python 2.

Comment: Double check that - if you are using Python 3, then the quote marks shouldn't appear.

Comment: Oops, I got it now. I was using a wrong version. Thanks for a heads up.

Comment: can you upvote the answer too please - btw - which version did you use ? The main issue with either version is that they rely on the data being perfect, any error in the input file and they will break in possibly unexpected ways.

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> import re # Import regular expression python module
>>> with open('in','r') as f:  # Open the file
...     text = f.read()        # Read the contents
# Get all the years based on the regular expression, which in this case is extracts all the 4 digits and 1 digit numbers seperated by `\n` 
>>> values = re.findall(r'([0-9]{4})\n([0-9]{1})', text) 
>>> values
[('2001', '3'), ('2002', '1'), ('2002', '1'), ('2002', '2'), ('2002', '3')]
>>> a = raw_input('Enter year to count its winners:')  # Input
>>> b = '1' 
>>> j=(a,b) # create this tuple based on your query 
>>> output = sum([ 1 for i in year_count if i==j]) # Get the total gold for that year 
>>> print 'Gold Medals: ',output  # Output
```

Comment: if you are going to introduce complex stuff like regular expression you need to explain them, when the OP is clear a new user.

Comment: @TonySuffolk66 : Added comments for each line.

Comment: +1 for the comments - to be honest : I have been coding python for nearly 3 years, and I still don't go near reg expressions unless there is no other solution. I find them almost completely unreadable (that isn't a python issue, it is a "Tony's brain" issue).

Comment: Its not your problem , regular expressions are indeed unreadable.

Answer (score 0):

A simple fix would use an iterator and ask for the next line:

```
lines = iter(openFile.read().split('\n'))
for line in lines:
    if year in line:
        line = next(lines)
        if str(1) in line:
            goldmedal = goldmedal + 1
```

A proper fix would be to split with `'\n\n'` and process the blocks as a group of data about a certain medal.

Answer (score 0):

I think I would write it this way:

```
kind={1: 'Gold', 2: 'Silver', 3: 'Bronze'}
fields=('last', 'first', 'year', 'medal')
year='2002'

data=[]
with open(fn) as f:
    txt=f.read()
    for block in txt.split('\n\n'):
        data.append({k:v for k, v in zip(fields, block.splitlines())})

counts={}
for e in data:
    key=int(e['medal'])
    counts[key] = counts.setdefault(key, 0) + 1

print('For {}:'.format(year))     
for key in counts:
    print('\t{:7} {}'.format(kind[key]+':', counts[key]))
```

Prints:

```
For 2002:
    Gold:   2
    Silver: 1
    Bronze: 2
```